# Rails - open_hours: Looping all days of week even not saved at DB (set as closed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Venue model that has_many and accept_nested_attributes_for working_hours.

The Working Hour model:

```
create_table "working_hours", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "day"
  t.time     "open_time"
  t.time     "close_time"
  t.integer  "venue_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.index ["merchant_id"], name: "index_working_hours_on_merchant_id", using: :btree
end
```

At my view I create a list  to show the open_time and close_time according day of week, as:

```
<ul class="working-hours-body">
  <% @merchant.working_hours.order(:day).each do |wh| %>
    <li>
      <%= t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[wh.day.to_i] %> : 
      <%= wh.open_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)  %> -
      <%= wh.close_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)  %> 
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Supposing I create records for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday. At the list are showed as:

```
Monday:    8am - 17pm
Tuesday:   8am - 17pm
Wednesday: 8am - 17pm
Thursday:  8am - 17pm
Friday:    8am - 17pm
```

**What is the best approach to show the Saturday and Sunday as Closed?**

```
Monday:    8am - 17pm
Tuesday:   8am - 17pm
Wednesday: 8am - 17pm
Thursday:  8am - 17pm
Friday:    8am - 17pm
Saturday:  closed
Sunday:    closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="working-hours-body">
  <% (0..6).to_a.each do |day| %>
    <li>
      <% wh = @merchant.working_hours.find_by(day: day) %>
      <% if wh %>
        <%= t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[day] %> : 
        <%= wh.open_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)  %> -
        <%= wh.close_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)  %> 
      <% else %>
        <%= t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[day] %> : Closed
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
```

To support multiple date ranges in a day, do this...

```
<ul class="working-hours-body">
  <% (0..6).to_a.each do |day| %>
    <li>
      <%= t(:"date.abbr_day_names")[day] %> :
      <% wh = @merchant.working_hours.where(day: day) %>
      <% if wh.present? %>
        <%= wh.map{|slot| "#{slot.open_time.to_formatted_s(:hours_and_minutes)} - #{slot.close_time.to_formatted_s(:hours_and_minutes)}"}.join(', ')  
      <% else %>
        <%= " Closed" %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. Save my life!! =)

Comment: No problem, I've been working on similar code this month!  It was slightly more demanding as I had to combine consecutive days with same opening times into a single line... `Mon to Thu : 8 am to 5 pm, Fri: 8 am to 8pm, Sat to Sun: Closed`

Comment: Steve, One doubt: With the suggesting code when I create more than one working hour block per day, the last one are hidden. Ex: Sunday 10am - 12am Sunday 10pm - 12pm The second one are hidden. Is it possible to show both of them at same line like Sunday 10am - 12 am / 10pm - 12pm? I tried change the <% if wh %> block to <%= @merchant.working_hours.collect { |h| "#{h.open_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)} - #{h.close_time.to_formatted_s(:hour_and_minutes)}" }.join(' / ') %> But the code return all records from that merchant. Any idea?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show `Sunday 10am - 12am, 10pm - 12pm` for days with multiple working hour records. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Steve,

It works perfectly. 

Thank You for the amazing help. 

Have a nice week!!